# Covariant derivate of a ortogonal endomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am working with different topics of Riemannian geometry and I have a little problem with a question. Assume that $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold endowed with the Levi Civita connection. Let $P$ be a $(1,1)$-tensor field, i.e., $P$ is a endomorphism of fields
$$
P : \mathfrak{X}(M) \to \mathfrak{X}(M)
$$

Assume that $P$ is fibered with respect $TM$, that's mean if $p \in M$ and $X_p \in T_pM$ then $P(X_p) \in T_pM$, i.e., $P$ is a $TM$-endomorphism (attending to its bundle nature). Assume that $P$ is orthogonal with respect each metric, that is
$$
g_p(P(v_p),P(v_p)) = g_p(v_p,v_p).
$$

I have two a question that I can't solve:

1. Can I say anything about $\nabla P$? I know that
   $$
   P(\nabla_X Y)) = \nabla_X P(Y) - (\nabla_X P)(Y)
   $$
   I'm especially interested in the relation among
   $$
   \langle E_i, \nabla_X E_i\rangle \stackrel{???}{=} \langle P(E_i), \nabla_X P(E_i)\rangle 
   $$
   (that is the connection 1-forms in different orthonormal frames).
2. I know every closed differential form $\alpha$ in a simply connected is exact. Is there any theorem related to the covariant derivate? If $T$ is a tensor field $(r,s)$, the contraction $i_X \nabla T = \nabla_X T$ is another tensor field of type $(r,s)$. My question is if $T$ is a tensor field, there exists any tensor field $S$ such that $i_X \nabla S = T$?